# How to rewrite the folder path with RewriteRule command in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with understanding the URL rewriting rule.

My URL is

```
http://example.com/katalog/selection/book.php
```

and I would like to change the URL with `RewriteRule` to

```
http://example.com/selection
```

my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://example.com/katalog/selection/book.php$ http://example.com/selection [R=301,L]
```

but I can't access the new path.

Comment: RewriteRule does not match on full URLs, it matches on the path component of the URL only.

Answer (score 1):

As CBroe mentioned in comments, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the the URL-path only, not the scheme+hostname+path. However, "but I can't access the new path" suggests that you want to *internally rewrite* the request from `/selection` to `/katalog/selection/book.php` - which is the complete opposite of what you are trying to do. (Although `/selection` looks a bit too *general*?)

Try something like the following in your root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^selection$ katalog/selection/book.php [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash in per-directory `.htaccess` files.

Now request the URL `/selection` and the request will be *internally rewritten* (visible web address does not change) to the file `/katalog/selection/book.php`.

Note you will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as 301s are cached hard by the browser.